Let $f(x, y) = x \log (x/y)$; why does the convention $f(0, 0) = 0$ make sense?
Define a function on a pair of positive reals,
$$
f(x, y) = x \log (x/y). 
$$
For any pair of (strictly) positive reals clearly $f(x, y)$ is well-defined.
We then would like to extend this function at points of the form $(x, 0), (0, y)$ where $x, y > 0$. For these, it is natural to proceed continuously:
$$
f(x, 0) = \lim_{y \to 0^+} x \log (x/y) = \infty
\quad 
f(0, y) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} x \log (x/y) = 0.
$$
However, I am unsure what to set $f(0, 0)$ to. Clearly if $x, y \to 0^+$ with $x/y\to c \in [0, \infty)$ then the natural thing would be to set the limit to $0$. However, if $x/ y \to \infty$, then what are the possible values of $\lim_{x, y \to 0^+, x/y \to \infty} f(x, y)$?

there’s no continuous extension to the origin, so there’s no natural definition for $f(0,0)$. So, your title question doesn’t really make sense.

The convention requires a suitable arbitrary choice, such as $\lim_{y\to0^+}\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x,,y)$. This is a classic example of limits not commuting.

Thanks for the discussion; this is what I suspected. In my answer I compute various paths where the limit 0, finite, or infinite.

Since $x,y\gt0$ the quotient when $\dfrac xy$ is near to the form $\frac 00$ takes any value, say $a\in\mathbb R$which will be killed by $x\to0$.

The convention requires fixing an order of limits.

To see why, consider $(x, y) = (t, t^2)$. Then
$$ \lim_{t\to 0^+} f(t, t^2) = -\lim_{t \to 0^+} t \log (t) = 0.$$
On the other hand, consider the pair $(x, y) = (t, t e^{-1/t})$
Then
$$
\lim_{t\to 0^+} f(t, t e^{-1/t}) = 1. 
$$
We can make the situation even worse,
$$
\lim_{t\to 0^+} f(t, t e^{-1/t^2}) = \lim_{t\to 0^+} t^{-1} = \infty.
$$
Any limit is possible.

ok nice these were exactly the families of paths I considered (more generally, $\gamma(t)=(t,cte^{-1/t^{\alpha}})$ for suitable $c,\alpha>0$).

Yeah for completeness, using the pre constant $c$ allows you to see that any finite limit is possible.

@peek-a-boo is there a general principle that would allow one to see "in advance" that the limit here is not well-defined? (Meaning conditions on the function $f(x, y)$ that are necessary and sufficient for the existence of the limit at the origin)

no, but here when you have polynomials and logarithms interacting, (or polynomials and exponentials) you immediately see that the different rates at which things go to $0$ matter. So, if you had instead $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}\log(x/y)$, then this would be better, because $t\mapsto t\log t$ has a continuous extension to $[0,\infty)$.
